# outof sync after execute mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

i met a issue during my development on mysql and linux C.
as the procedure use temporary params, so I think it will not affect following sql query. but my test is failed and report errno:2014.

the procedure I used is :

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists pbx_r_eid_svcid;
CREATE PROCEDURE `pbx_r_eid_svcid`(IN input_eid varchar(16))
begin

declare exe_result int default -1;
declare out_svcip varchar(64) default "";
declare out_svcport varchar(64) default "";

select exe_result,out_svcip,out_svcport;

end;//
delimiter;
```

C code:

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
MYSQL *mysql;
int timeout=atoi(argv[1]);
char escape[64] = "";
char orig[64] = "";
char buf[128] = "";
int rc = 0;

MYSQL_RES *res;

mysql = mysql_init(NULL);

mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, &timeout);
mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT, &timeout);

mysql_real_connect(mysql, "127.0.0.1", "root", "123456", "center_distribute", 3306,"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS | CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS);

snprintf(buf,128, "call pbx_r_eid_svcid('00000002')", "11");

if (mysql_real_query(mysql,buf,strlen(buf)))
{
   int err_no = mysql_errno(mysql);
   fprintf(stderr, "Failed to insert row, Error: %d %s\n", err_no,
           mysql_error(mysql));
}

res = mysql_store_result(mysql);
if(0 == mysql_affected_rows(mysql) || res == NULL)
{
    rc = 6;
    goto end;
}

mysql_free_result(res);


snprintf(buf,128,"select * from enterprise_info;");
/******************************/
/*wrong query return out of sync*/
if (mysql_real_query(mysql,buf,strlen(buf)))
{
   int err_no = mysql_errno(mysql);
   fprintf(stderr, "Failed to insert row, Error: %d %s\n", err_no,
           mysql_error(mysql));
}
res = mysql_store_result(mysql);
if(0 == mysql_affected_rows(mysql) || res == NULL)
{
    rc = 7;
    goto end;
}

mysql_free_result(res);

end:
printf("%d\n",rc);
mysql_close(mysql);
return 0;
}
```

second mysql select will repsonse out of sync error

test reult:
./mt 5

Failed to insert row, Error: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this 
command now

7

any comment should be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: close it : http://www.programering.com/a/MTMzEzMwATM.html

Comment: do
     {
      if (mysql_field_count(mysql_in) > 0)
      {
            res = mysql_store_result(mysql_in);
            mysql_free_result(res);
      }
     }
     while (mysql_next_result(mysql_in) == 0);

Comment: As procedure can return multily result, so after call procedure, need to release all result by loop process.